# Read pdf without headers and footers and insert a new line only after ,?! [java]

Tags: java, pdf, newline, header-files, pdfbox

I have many pdf files (articles with different format). I want to read the content and write it in a .txt file but ignoring the headers and footers and also I would like to have a new line only after the following symbols: .?!

Is it possible?
I have used PDFBox, I have removed the new lines from middle of the sentences, but I don't know to add a new line at the ending of one sentence. Also in my read text are also the headers and footers.

My actual code:

```
    PDDocument pd;
    BufferedWriter wr;
    String outputFilename = filename.split(".pdf")[0] + ".txt";
    try {
        File input = new File(filename);  // The PDF file from where you would like to extract
        File output = new File(outputFilename); // The text file where you are going to store the extracted data
        pd = PDDocument.load(input);
        System.out.println("Output filename:" + output.getName());
        System.out.println("Number of pages:" + pd.getNumberOfPages());
        System.out.println("Encrypted:" + pd.isEncrypted());
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper()
        {
            @Override
            protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text)
            {
                String character = text.getCharacter();
                if (character != null && character.trim().length() != 0)
                    super.processTextPosition(text);
            }
        };
        stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
        stripper.setLineSeparator("");
        wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));
        wr.write(stripper.getText(pd));
        //stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
        if (pd != null) {
            pd.close();
        }
        wr.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also I have a problem with documents with 2 columns format like: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bfba/e458f1a31e57dbae321208e00113d670ea00.pdf . when I extract text I get a text file where columns are merged as the result (i.e. text from both columns in the same line)

Thanks!

Comment: By which criteria can software recognize headers and footers in your PDFs? Are they tagged?

Comment: No specific pattern. For example I have one pdf like this https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bfba/e458f1a31e57dbae321208e00113d670ea00.pdf . The files are from different domains so there is no defined pattern of words.

Comment: I looked at the sample PDF. There indeed is nothing special about the headers. Thus, if you want to *ignore the headers and footers*, you have to provide external criteria for that.